# AttributeError: 'Figure' object has no attribute 'set_layout_engine'

Tags: python

I am running a ggplot code in jupyter notebook. I've installed plotnine, but when I try to run, it give me the error **AttributeError: 'Figure' object has no attribute 'set_layout_engine'**

The code is so symple:

```
(     ggplot(df_nousd)              
       + aes(x="raised_currency_code")              
       + geom_bar(color="blue", alpha = 0.2)              
       + labs(title='Tipo de moneda, capital por startup',                                
               x ='Tipo de moneda',                               
               y = 'Cuantía')  
)
```

Appear:

---

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
\~\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\IPython\\core\\formatters.py in __call__(self, obj)
700                 type_pprinters=self.type_printers,
701                 deferred_pprinters=self.deferred_printers)
\--\> 702             printer.pretty(obj)
703             printer.flush()
704             return stream.getvalue()

\~\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\IPython\\lib\\pretty.py in pretty(self, obj)
392                         if cls is not object \
393                                 and callable(cls.__dict__.get('__repr__')):
\--\> 394                             return \_repr_pprint(obj, self, cycle)
395
396             return \_default_pprint(obj, self, cycle)

\~\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\IPython\\lib\\pretty.py in _repr_pprint(obj, p, cycle)
698     """A pprint that just redirects to the normal repr function."""
699     # Find newlines and replace them with p.break_()
\--\> 700     output = repr(obj)
701     lines = output.splitlines()
702     with p.group():

\~\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\plotnine\\ggplot.py in __repr__(self)
112         Print/show the plot
113         """
\--\> 114         figure = self.draw(show=True)
115
116         dpi = figure.get_dpi()

\~\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\plotnine\\ggplot.py in draw(self, show)
239             # Artist object theming
240             self.theme.apply()
\--\> 241             figure.set_layout_engine(PlotnineLayoutEngine(self))
242
243         return self.figure

AttributeError: 'Figure' object has no attribute 'set_layout_engine'
```

Anyone can help with this error?

I was searching here some solution, but nowhere appear a similar error with that report.

Comment: This is not close to being a minimal reproducible example. Do the examples [here](https://github.com/has2k1/plotnine#example) work without that error in your hands? What has to be added to the code in those examples to trigger the specific error you are seeing? Please see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), in particular the section under 'Help others reproduce the problem'.